# Shapefile type description showing attribute error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, shapefile, pycharm, attributeerror

```
import arcpy
esc = arcpy.Describe("C:\Users\Drona_Maps\Desktop\lecture16\shapefiles\world_continents.shp")
print esc.ShapeType
```

Shape file type description showing attribute error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Drona_Maps/Desktop/ARCPY/1st project/CHAPTER 4 exercise part 1.py", line 3, in <module>
    print esc.ShapeType
AttributeError: DescribeData: Method ShapeType does not exist

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Be careful with Windows path separators: They need to be escaped or used in raw formatting. Python is case-sensitive, so you Mus use the functions as named. It is not best practice to include spaces in directory names.

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, add `r` literal to path string like `r"C:\Users\.....`, secondly, use `shapeType` instead of `ShapeType`.